# Delete all dataframe groups for which any column contains NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Sample data,

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), v1=c(NA,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), v2=c(4,5,6,4,5,6,4,NA,6))
```

Looks like,

```
  ID v1 v2
1  1 NA  4
2  1  2  5
3  1  3  6
4  2  1  4
5  2  2  5
6  2  3  6
7  3  1  4
8  3  2 NA
9  3  3  6
```

And I would like to obtain,

```
  ID v1 v2
4  2  1  4
5  2  2  5
6  2  3  6
```

I have tried,

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!anyNA(c(v1,v2)))

df2
```

Which produces the desired results, however:

- I have over 70 columns, there must be a better way than writing c(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5...)
- Creating a second dataframe (df2 <- df) feels messy, is there a way to directly change my initial dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` for `is.na(df[-1])`, use `ave` with `any` and grouping by `df$ID` and take the rows with `FALSE`. You can overwrite `df`.

```
df <- df[!ave(rowSums(is.na(df[-1])) > 0L, df$ID, FUN=any), ]

df
#  ID v1 v2
#4  2  1  4
#5  2  2  5
#6  2  3  6
```

---

Benchmark

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), v1=c(NA,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), v2=c(4,5,6,4,5,6,4,NA,6))
dt <- copy(df)

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
ave = df[!ave(rowSums(is.na(df[-1])) > 0L, df$ID, FUN=any), ],
"Chris Ruehlemann" = {df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(if_all(starts_with("v"), ~!anyNA(.)))},
"TarJae1" = {df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, row)) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(value))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from = value) %>% 
    select(-row)},
"TarJae2" = {df %>% 
  anti_join(df %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% 
            filter(if_any(everything(), ~is.na(.))) , by = "ID")},
"TarJae3" = {df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~anyNA(.)), .by=ID) },
"ThomasIsCoding" = setDT(dt)[ID == dt[, !anyNA(.SD), ID][V1 == TRUE, ID]]
)
```

Result

```
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 ave              114.16µs 120.22µs    8185.   105.02KB     44.8  3653    20
2 Chris Ruehlemann      3ms   3.06ms     319.     3.36MB     36.8   130    15
3 TarJae1           13.06ms  13.21ms      74.5    1.26MB     58.8    19    15
4 TarJae2            3.56ms   3.62ms     271.   413.95KB     38.0   107    15
5 TarJae3            3.39ms   3.46ms     284.    60.04KB     40.5   112    16
6 ThomasIsCoding     1.41ms   1.53ms     650.     2.83MB     15.1   258     6
```

In this case `ave` is about 12 times faster than the second and `TarJae3` allocates the lowest additional memory.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(if_all(starts_with("v"), ~!anyNA(.)))
```

Here we address the columns in question by the letter they all start with, "v", using `starts_with`. There are multiple `dplyr` functions to address columns without hard-coding their names; check out `ends_with`, `contains`, and (my favorite) `matches`, which is regex-sensitive

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I should have mentioned v1,v2,v3... were just placeholders - my actual variables start with just about every letter under the sun... Replacing 'starts_with("v")' with 'everything()' (per the answer belows) works though!

Answer (score 2):

**Update2**

Inspired by the use of `anyNA` by @Chris Ruehlemann I found this final version:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~anyNA(.)), .by=ID) 

  ID v1 v2
1  2  1  4
2  2  2  5
3  2  3  6
```

**Update1 improved code:**
A `dplyr` only solution:

```
df %>% 
  anti_join(df %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% 
              filter(if_any(everything(), ~is.na(.))) , by = "ID")

  ID v1 v2
1  2  1  4
2  2  2  5
3  2  3  6
```

**First answer:**
Here is `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, row)) %>%
  filter(!any(is.na(value))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

```
     ID    v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     1     4
2     2     2     5
3     2     3     6
```

Answer (score 2):

here are some `data.table` options:

```
> setDT(df)[ID == df[, !anyNA(.SD), ID][, ID[V1]]
   ID v1 v2
1:  2  1  4
2:  2  2  5
3:  2  3  6
```

or

```
> rbindlist(Filter(Negate(anyNA), split(df, ~ID)))
   ID v1 v2
1:  2  1  4
2:  2  2  5
3:  2  3  6
```

or even shorter (thank's for the comment from @Henrik)

```
> setDT(df)[, if(!anyNA(.SD)) .SD, ID]
   ID v1 v2
1:  2  1  4
2:  2  2  5
3:  2  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
subset(df, ID %in% names(which(!sapply(split(df[-1], ~ ID), anyNA))))
```

-output

```
  ID v1 v2
4  2  1  4
5  2  2  5
6  2  3  6
```